# The single chosen select will never get focus if navigate using tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I am using a Chosen jQuery plugin. In which the single chosen select will never get focus if navigate using tabs but It works fine for the multiple chosen select.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Select:</label>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <select data-placeholder="Select" class="chosen-select" name="releaseState"
            tabindex="1" style="width: 100%;">
            <option value="1">is</option>
            <option value="2">is not</option>
            <option value="3">all</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <select data-placeholder="Select option"
            class="chosen-select" name="optionSelect" tabindex="2"
            style="width: 100%;" multiple>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the console also it is not showing any errors.

Thanks for Help.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/yffqn0st/

Comment: Corret me if I'm missunderstanding your question, but you're asking for page navigation through the tab button? Well, for me, I can focus on both, the input field and the select, using my tab button.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. 
Could you please look at this.             JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/Prafulla_Pol/Lm1vvaq1/

Multiple select is opening on the tab but single select is only get highlighted. It is not opening. How can i open the single select same as the multiple select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the question, you are using chosen select Jquery for selection option from single chosen selector. But as per my understanding jquery chosen (v1.5.1) not supported specified features.
refer for the same :[Chosen V1.5.1](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)
applicable only for multi chosen select.